# Delete rows on two different sheets based on cell value in a more efficient way [VBA Excel]

Tags: excel, vba

I have a two different worksheets with the same number of rows each one. In column R I have "New" or "Old" depending on the row (this is a dynamic value). What I want to do is, if a row in Worksheet1 contains "Old" in column R, then delete that row in both Worksheet1 and Worksheet2.

Now, I have tried two codes for this:

```
Dim w1 As Worksheet
Dim w2 As Worksheet

Set w1= Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set w2= Worksheets("Sheet2")
'-----------------------------------------------------
'Code 1
'-----------------------------------------------------
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 For r = w1.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
     If Cells(r, "R") = "Old" Then
         w1.Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete
         w2.Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete
     End If
 Next r
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'-----------------------------------------------------
'Code 2
'-----------------------------------------------------

Dim i As Long

i = 1
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Do While i <= w1.Range("R1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

If InStr(1, w1.Cells(i, 18).Text, "Old", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    w1.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    w2.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
Else
    i = i + 1
End If

Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Usually I have +800 rows, so Code 1 works as desired but it sometimes takes too long, like 3 minutes. Code 2 gets stuck so far.

What is an efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Delete Rows In Sheets

Implementing **Union** should considerably speed up the process.

### The Code

```
Sub DeleteRowsInSheets()

    Const cSheet1 As Variant = "Sheet1"    ' First Worksheet Name/Index
    Const cSheet2 As Variant = "Sheet2"    ' First Worksheet Name/Index
    Const cVntCol As Variant = "R"         ' Search Column Letter/Number
    Const cStrCriteria As String = "Old"   ' Search Criteria String

    Dim rngU1 As Range   ' Union Range 1
    Dim rngU2 As Range   ' Union Range 2
    Dim LastUR As Long   ' Last Used Row
    Dim i As Long        ' Row Counter

    With Worksheets(cSheet1)

        ' Calculate Last Used Row.
        If .Cells.Find("*", .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), -4123, , 1) _
                Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        LastUR = .Cells.Find("*", , , , , 2).Row

        ' Add found cells to Union Ranges.
        For i = 1 To LastUR
            If StrComp(.Cells(i, cVntCol), cStrCriteria, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                If Not rngU1 Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngU1 = Union(rngU1, .Cells(i, 1))
                    Set rngU2 = Union(rngU2, Worksheets(cSheet2).Cells(i, 1))
                  Else
                    Set rngU1 = .Cells(i, 1)
                    Set rngU2 = Worksheets(cSheet2).Cells(i, 1)
                End If
            End If
        Next

    End With

    ' Delete rows.
    If Not rngU1 Is Nothing Then
        rngU1.EntireRow.Delete ' Hidden = True
        rngU2.EntireRow.Delete ' Hidden = True
        Set rngU2 = Nothing
        Set rngU1 = Nothing
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Using `LCase` for case-insensitive comparison is wrong. If you do need to compare case-insensitively (which is not clear from the OP's question), use `If StrComp(.Cells(i, cVntCol), cStrCriteria, vbTextCompare) = 0`. There was no need to replace the OP's `UsedRange` with two calls to `Find` either, it is not related to the problem and does make the code look more confusing.

Comment: @GSerg: I've seen  the use of LCase by a bigger fish than me and assumend it was correct. Thanks. I had some bad experiences with UsedRange e.g . I delete a row in it and the UsedRange doesn't change, I mean its address stays the same. Do you have any advice or a link how to  know when it is safe to be used?

Comment: Thank you so much! So far this worked like a charm, from 3 minutes to very few seconds. And thank you for the indications/comments on your code.

Comment: @VBasic2008 did you try with 20.000 rows ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that there could be lots of formulas. So Application.Calculation = xlManual at the begining and Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic at the end should be good idea too.

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For r = w1.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
     If Cells(r, "R") = "Old" Then
         w1.Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete
         w2.Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete
     End If
 Next r
Application.ScreenUpdating = true
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Comment: I need the formulas to be updated while the macro is running, there are autofills and vlookups searching in those cells that have been autofilled, and so, I can't unable those calculations. This really ran in seconds! But unfortunately didn't returned what was expected.